# GoogleApiClient connection fails with error codes 5005 and 5007

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-api-client, google-fit-sdk

One of our users reports that he sees the errors 5005 and 5007 in the app.

I haven't detected those errors while implementing the google fit features neither while working with fit samples on any of my devices.

Would be good to know more details on what those status codes actually mean since it's not really clear from [API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/FitnessStatusCodes) docs.

Specially it's really strange since the app works fine in several devices I tried. So if there's some operation not supported by Google Fit, it wouldn't work on any device.

Comment: You might want to check this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38416844/5995040), the user may be encountering issue on Fit and connecting with wearable devices. Check if you are implementing `useDefaultAccount` when connecting to wearable devices and which FIT account to access and read.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already checked that post. No, not using useDefaultAccount. Also I know that the user used nexus 5, and no wearables.